# Solving homogeneous Cauchy-Euler ODE for $t<0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My textbook reads:

**We remark that if a homogeneous Cauchy-Euler equation is to be solved for $t>0$, then one simply introduces the change of variables $t=-\tau$, where $\tau >0$. I'm trying to verify this for a homogeneous Cauchy-Euler equation of the form

$$at^2y''(t)+bty'(t)+cy(t)=0$$

However when I plug in $y=(-t)^r$ in the equation, I have

$$y=(-t)^r; y'=-r(-t)^{r-1}; y''=r(r-1)(-t)^{r-2}$$

When I plug this into the Cauchy Euler equation, I don't get the characteristic equation that I SHOULD be getting, given by

$$ar^2+(b-a)r+c$$

I end up getting

$$\:at^2\left(r\left(r-1\right)\left(-t\right)^{r-2}\right)+bt\left(-r\left(-t\right)^{r-1}\right)+c\left(-t\right)^r$$

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Note that $t(-r(-t)^{r-1})=r(-t)^r$, so that the sign is absorbed "internally".

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks.